# How can I do child routing in a reusable (generic) module?

Tags: angular

I have a custom person module which I want to package and then reuse in different applications.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'mod-person-grid',
  template: `<h1><ng-content></ng-content></h1>`
})
class PersonGridComponent { @Input() type: string; }

const personRoutes: Routes = [
  { 
     path: '',   
     component: PersonGridComponent,
      children: [
      {
        path: 'view/:id', 
        component: PersonDetailsComponent,
       }
    ]
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ CommonModule, RouterModule.forChild(personRoutes) ],
  declarations: [ PersonGridComponent, PersonDetailsComponent ],
  exports: [ PersonGridComponent ]
})
export class PersonModule {
  static forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders {
    return {
      ngModule: PersonModule,
      providers: [ PersonService ]
    }
  }
}
```

So I can have an employee application that uses the person component to view staff members and when selecting a particular staff to view its details.

Or I will have a student application where I use the same person module to view all persons of type 'student' and upon clicking a particular student, show its details.

However I can not get the routing to working inside this person module between the grid and detail views, depending on the parent application (employee or student) links.

Here is a plunker to show what I want to do:[routing_in_module](https://plnkr.co/edit/5zuwz3KnaarWI57eBhtO?p=preview)

My EmployeeComponent uses "employees" routes and the StudentComponent uses "students" routes.

```
@Component({
  template: `<mod-person-grid [type]="'staff'">Manage Employees</mod-person-grid>`
})
class EmployeesComponent { }

@Component({
  template: `<mod-person-grid [type]="'student'">Manage Students</mod-person-grid>`
})
class StudentsComponent { }

const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: '',   redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'home',  component: HomeComponent },
  { path: 'employees',  component: EmployeesComponent },
  { path: 'students',  component: StudentsComponent },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule, RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes), PersonModule.forRoot() ],
  declarations: [ App, HomeComponent, EmployeesComponent, StudentsComponent ],
  bootstrap: [ App ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

The goal is to have PersonModule be generic as possible.

How can I route to the child "view" path inside the PersonModule depending on which app/component/link it originated from?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Took a while to get a hang of what the problem was. But finally managed to get it working as you wish.

If I understood you well, you need that both the `EmployeesComponent` and `StudentsComponent` which both use the `mod-person-grid` component (which in itself has a router outlet), be able to display the details of the the person that is chosen.

## Step 1

To be able to achieve the above, that is, the details of the person are rendered in the router outlet of the `mod-person-grid` component that are part of the template of both `Employees` and `Students` Components, the base route, rendering these components need to know any child routes that are to be rendered. These are the child routes defined in the `PersonsModule` and can be defined as follows.

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: '',   redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'home',  component: HomeComponent },
  { path: 'employees',  component: EmployeesComponent, loadChildren:'src/person.module.ts#PersonModule' },
  { path: 'students',  component: StudentsComponent, loadChildren:'src/person.module.ts#PersonModule' }
];
```

The above essentially says that the `employees` route, will render the content of the `EmployeesComponent` (which contains a router-outlet obtained from `mod-person-grid`), and also have child routes, that are obtained via the routes defined in `PersonsModule` which will be lazy loaded when necessary (achieved via `loadChildren`).

## Step 2

When the application was being loaded, it was erroneously also rendering the content of `PersonGridComponent` (which was breaking the overall content). This was happening because you were importing both the main routing config, and the route configuration defined in `PersonsModule` when importing it, in your app module.

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [ ..., RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes), PersonModule.forRoot() ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

This was creating a **conflict** between these two configurations :

**Route 1**

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: '',   redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'home',  component: HomeComponent }
];
```

and

**Route 2**

```
const personRoutes: Routes = [
  { 
     path: '',   
     component: PersonGridComponent,
      children: [ ... ]
  }
];
```

which were both stating that the empty path `''` should render the `home` route, achieved via redirect configured in **Route 1**, and the `PersonsGridComponent` that was configured in **Route 2**.

The **fix** for this problem was to map the configs of **Route 2** to a named outlet, like below

```
const personRoutes: Routes = [
  { 
     path: '',   
     component: PersonGridComponent,
     children: [ ... ],
     outlet: 'person'
  }
];
```

and the part in `PersonsGridComponent` handling the redirecting, to work like this

```
 <td><a [routerLink]="[{ outlets: { person: ['view', person.id]} }]">view</a></td>
```

Read more about named outlets [here](https://angular.io/guide/router#displaying-multiple-routes-in-named-outlets).

## Step 3

This last fix relates to an incorrect configuration in the `PersonsModule`. In your `PersonGridComponent` the redirect definition of the `routerLink`, specifies that the link must be `view/{id}`... however in your routing definition, you were binding the `view` part of your route, to the `PersonGridComponent`.

```
const personRoutes: Routes = [
  { 
     path: '', component: PersonGridComponent, // <- This here
     ...
  }
];
```

which would then breaks the rendering. This is not what you needed, rather, you needed to display the details of the person, through the `PersonDetailsComponent`. The routes have been updated as follows

```
const personRoutes: Routes = [
  { 
     path: 'view/:id',
     component: PersonDetailsComponent
     outlet: 'person'
  }
];
```

## Plunker

I've forked your plunker, and fixed your issues. You can see the full working solution [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/ryDFMGtYxI1WvzZh9Oav?p=preview).

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed explanation. It was easy to follow and understand. Today I learned something new..router outlets!